# C++ std::isupper con utf multibyte ¿Mayúsculas, minúsculas o ninguna de las dos?

Tags: c++, utf-8

La cabecera [`<locale>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/locale) de C++ nos da acceso a la función [`std::isupper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/isupper):

> ```
> template< class charT >
> bool isupper( charT ch, const locale& loc );
> ```
>
> Comprueba si el carácter facilitado está clasificado como un carácter alfabético en mayúsculas usando la faceta [`std::ctype`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/ctype) proveída en la configuración local.

Podemos ver que dicha función es una plantilla sobre el tipo de carácter `charT`. En C++ los [tipos de carácter son](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types#Character_types) (resaltado mío):

> - `signed char` - el tipo para representar caracteres con tipo.
> - `unsigned char` - el tipo para representar caracteres sin signo. También usado para inspeccionar la representación de objetos (memoria en crudo).
> - `char` - tipo para representar caracteres que puedan ser procesados de la manera más eficiente por el sistema (tiene la misma representación y alineamiento que `signed char` o `unsigned char`, pero es un tipo distinto). **Las cadenas multibyte usan este tipo para representar las unidades de código**. […]

Así que la función `std::isupper` recibe **un solo carácter** y determina si es mayúscula o minúscula, pero en el caso de codificaciones multibyte se necesita más de un carácter para determinar que carácter estamos consultando.

Al hacer una sencilla prueba con la letra `A` y la letra lluvia `雨`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>

int main()
{
    auto l = std::locale("");
    std::cout.imbue(l);
    std::cout
        << std::boolalpha
        << l.name()
        << "\n'A' isupper = " << std::isupper('A', l)
        << "\n'雨' isupper = " << std::isupper('雨', l);

    return 0;
}
```

[Obtengo la siguiente salida](https://tio.run/##hY07DsIwDEDn@BRWGZpKUDHTUol7sKRpBJGcj9JkQpyEC3A1TlH6AQETo5/fs6X3m5OUw7DSVlLqFNba9TEoYRr4MHJSkGoAtI1ohLa8gAswkaJDwj32sdvtFolnWVEBm4l0KZbatElx@oHAWF0vVescCfJnsTAqrTBqPD9P2dHmhxx1n7xXYXyU4bt7MT7u10hf/uN2/1NMxtRUACyomILFbQXXYXgC):

> ```
> en_US.UTF8
> 'A' isupper = true
> '雨' isupper =
> ```

No se ha impreso el resultado de `std::isupper('雨', l)` porque se ha lanzado una excepción:

> ```
> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_cast'
> what():  std::bad_cast
> ```

La documentación de [`std::bad_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/bad_cast) indica que esta excepción puede lanzarse cuando se intenta usar una faceta ([`std::use_facet`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/use_facet)) inexistente en la configuración local, por lo que el comportamiento es coherente, ya que la letra lluvia (雨) no existe en la configuración inglés (en) estadounidense (US). Por otro lado el compilador muestra una alarma:

> ```
> warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
>  << "\n'雨' isupper = " << std::isupper('雨', l);
>                                          ^~~~~
> ```

Está considerando la letra lluvia (雨) como un literal multicaracter (que lo es), lo cuál da lugar al problema que motiva esta pregunta:

¿Cómo se comprueba si un literal multicaracter es mayúscula/minúscula si la función que hace dicha comprobación recibe un solo carácter?

Comment: has echado un vistazo a esto? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25375274/multicharacter-literal-misunderstanding

Comment: @IriaPoncelaBlanco ese hilo de SOen va sobre una particularidad de MSVC, yo he compilado en gcc.

Comment: No existen mecanismos estándar (al menos que yo conozca) que den soporte a esta funcionalidad una vez abandonas ASCII. Supongo que será porque cada tabla de caracteres tiene su propia organización y no hay forma de estandarizar eso